# What is this strange attribute on a div element?

Tags: html

I used Chrome Developer Tools to inspect a webpage, and I found a div that has some attributes, such as `_v-041fae94`.  I have never seen such an attribute before when programming with HTML. The div element with the strange attribute is shown as below:

```
   < div class="bg-layer selected" _v-041fae94="" _v-053095d7="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div class="img-layer" _v-041fae94="" style="left: 0px; top: -4px; width: 656px; height: 1016px; opacity: 1;"> <img _v-041fae94="" src="http://img1.maka.im/WSAD5JJGBRW5A2PARRKP"></div>
```

Is it a custom attribute? I think it's not because I know that in HTML5 documents, custom attributes can only be used with `data-` as an attribute prefix. So what exactly is this strange attribute, and what is the 'attribute' use for?

[image: div tag with strange attribute capture]

Comment: It's probably some attribute added dynamically by JS. It'll validate the document since it's added dynamically. Totally valid? No. Someone who build that attribute never heard about data-* attributes probably or was afraid to conflict with another data-v-041fae94 attribute... which is also a nonsense.

Comment: Most likely a Chrome extension is doing that.

Comment: Yeap,The attribute is added dynamically by JS,But I don't konw why the developer want to add such a attribute dynamically,What It the attribute use for?